# How to remove the gap between input and label in HTML without CSS?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

Here is my HTML code which is a registration form. As you see there is a gap between Name and input part and another gap between E-mail and input part.

How can I remove those gaps without CSS?

```html
<center>
  <form>
    <table>
    
      <tr>
        <td>
          Name:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , placeholder="Name">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          E-mail:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" , placeholder="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>
          Message:
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="32" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit">Send your Message</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</center>
```

This is my output...

[image: This screenshot is my output]

I used **center** to make my form in the center of my page , i know it is **obsolete** , i just want to know if there is a way to delete gaps no matter if it is **obsolete**.

Comment: Be aware that `<center>` [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Also, for proper accessibility you should be using actual label elements and associating them with your inputs with the `for` attribute.

Comment: Are you asking how to right-align the text in those cells?

Comment: And why can't you use CSS? It's just HTML like the rest of it.

Comment: @isherwood i just wanted to use pure HTML  to get the answer. Thanks a lot for your information.

Comment: Again, a `style` tag is "pure" HTML.

Comment: The HTML <style> element contains style information for a document, or part of a document. **It contains CSS**, which is applied to the contents of the document @isherwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just align to the right.

```html
<center>
  <form>
    <table>
    
      <tr>
        <td align="right">
          Name:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , placeholder="Name">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">
          E-mail:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" , placeholder="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>
          Message:
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="32" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit">Send your Message</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: This will probably work, but the `align` attribute [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).